Корректно ли говорить "103 мужчины"?
Собирательные числительные не употребляются с крупными числами. Как тогда сказать?
Например,
На собрании присутсвовали 103 мужчины.


На собрании присутствовали 103 мужчины.  Не звучит?

Но вот ответ Справочной службы
№ 258397
Как правильно согласовать сто два и мужчина? Сто два 
мужчины?
ОТВЕТ: Да, так: сто два мужчины.
  
№ 269995  Существительные мужского рода в таких случаях 
могут употребляться и с собирательными, и с количественными 
числительными. Верно: два мужчины и двое мужчин, четыре 
пацана и четверо пацанов.


Можно сделать замену: На собрании присутствовали мужчины в количестве 103 человек.

В чем причина неблагозвучия? А 1-м склонении большинство существительных имеет женский род, поэтому собирательные числительные в количественных сочетаниях предпочтительнее.
№ 235342.  Как сказать правильно? НА КАРТИНЕ 
ИЗОБРАЖЕНО ТРОЕ МУЖЧИН или ТРИ МУЖЧИНЫ? ОТВЕТ. 
Предпочтителен первый вариант.



